# ruby on rails administration namespace and two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, namespaces, admin

I try create admin namespace. I need update categories there. I have two controllers for dategories. One in folder categories (only for index) and one in cotrollers/administration (for update and create). But when i try update some category i get error:
    The action 'update' could not be found for CategoriesController

Category controller in controller folder:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  include Watchables::Watch

  default_tab :all, only: :index

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @categories = Category.order(:name)
    @tags       = Tag.order(:name)
  end
end
```

Category controller in controller/administration folder:

```
class Administration::CategoriesController < AdministrationController
  authorize_resource

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    if @category.update_attributes(category_params)
      flash[:notice] = t('category.update.success')
    else
      form_error_messages_for @category
    end
end
```

Why i get these error when i have  action update? How to get update from second controller? Because when i write update in controllers/categories it works fine.

EDIT:

```
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <%= form_for category do |f| %>
     <div class="modal-header">
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: :'form-control', rows: 1 %>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :tags %>
        <%= f.text_field :tags, class: :'form-control', data: { as: :select2, role: :tags } %>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><%= t 'category.edit.cancel' %></button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><%= t 'category.edit.submit' %></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the error stack trace? It will hint where it went wrong (I'm assuming after clicking a button it hit a wrong controller). Also the view that has category <form> would be useful.

Comment: @NikitaChernov i thing there is no problem in form because when i write update action in first controller then it works fine. And error is only : 
Unknown action
The action 'update' could not be found for CategoriesController
Nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route for `update` action in `admin` namespace is different from the default one:

right now you have:

`<%= form_for category do |f| %>`

that should display your path to update action like: `/categories/1` but it should look like `/administration/categories/1` and it will point to `update` action from `categories_controller` in `administration` namespace.

so the form should look something like:

`<%= form_for category, url: admin_category_path(category) do |f| %>`

depending what your routes says. Run `rake routes` for this.